# Javascript promise call happens just one time

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

## Some Context

Im running a nodejs aplication that works with the Twit API.

Im using it to periodically tweet some images on tweeter, to generate the images im using processing (java API)

So im using the 'fs' lib of nodejs to execute the command: 
`processing-java --sketch="%cd%"\\processing\\sketch --run`

Then im using a eventListener to know when processing is closed to load the generated image, to do this im using this JS promise:

File: **generate-sketch-images.js**

```
const {exec} = require('child_process');
const fs = require('fs');
module.exports = new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
        let cmd = `processing-java --sketch="%cd%"\\processing\\sketch --run`;
        console.log('running processing');
        exec(cmd).addListener('close',() => {
            resolve(fs.readFileSync(
            'processing/paints/paint.png',
            {encoding:'base64'}
            ));
            console.log('image received from processing');
        });
    })
```

Then i made this function:

File: **bot.js**

```
const generate_image = require('./utils/generate-sketch-images');

async function gerar_imagem(){
    console.log('generating the image');
    let img = await generate_image;
}
```

## The problem

The 'gerar_imagens' function **only** works at first time

When i do something like `setInterval(gerar_imagens,1000);` it works just one time

I have already made a lot of console logs, and seems like the function call happens but the promise is ignored

someone knows whats happening??

Comment: You should export a function that returns a new Promise each time it's called. Right now you only create one Promise ever and export it (which also means the image generation starts as soon as you require your js file instead of when you want to trigger it). Change your call to `await generateImage();` and change your export line to `module.exports = function ( ) { return new Prom... }`

Comment: great, that worked, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :)